# How import data using controller to view in Laravel 8.*

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I would like to go to specific object view from main page(index). Here is how I communicate with page which is about to be showed

```
{{ route('object',['id'=>$object->id]) }}
```

Error message:

[image]

Error message says that it should be something wrong with controller, but in previous case this code worked.

**web.php(routes)**

```
Route::get('/object/{id}','FrontendController@object')->name('object');
```

**My FrontendController**

```
use App\Interfaces\FrontendRepositoryInterface;

class FrontendController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(FrontendRepositoryInterface $frontendRepository)
    {
        $this->fR = $frontendRepository;
    }


    public function index()
    {
        $objects = $this->fR->getObjectsForMainPage();
        //dd($objects);
        return view('frontend.index',['objects'=>$objects]);
    }

    public function object($id)
    {
        $object = $this->fR->getObject($id);
        //dd($objects);
        return view('frontend.object',['object'=>$object]);
    }
```

**FrontendRepository**

```
use App\Models\EventObject;
use App\Models\Photo;
use App\Interfaces\FrontendRepositoryInterface;


class FrontendRepository implements FrontendRepositoryInterface {

    public function getObjectsForMainPage()
    {
        return EventObject::with(['photos','clubs'])->get();
    }

    public function getObject($id)
    {
        return EventObject::with(['photos','clubs'])->get();
    }

}
```

Comment: try with this `{{ route('object',$object->id) }}`

Comment: @Pradeep it deleted = from url but didnt solve problem.

Comment: keeping in mind routing syntax is different in 8x from others versions

Comment: @Pradeep I do keep it in mind. But for index where i didnt use /{id} it worked. That's why its mystery for me now.

Comment: show me your  a tag where u defining the routes

Comment: @Pradeep I dont know really what you are asking me about Sir. In which file should it be?

Comment: did u implement this code `{{ route('object',$object->id) }}` if yes what error u got

Comment: notice that in your url, you have `..object?id=2`. It is supposed to be `..object/2` according to route definition. Do you perhaps have a repeat route name? Maybe your route pointing to index is also named 'object' and that one is interfering with this one..maybe.

Comment: @Pradeep After implementing {{ route('object',$object->id) }} url changes to .../object?4
so everything im missing is / probably in exchange of ?.
My index route: Route::get('/','FrontendController@index')->name('index');

Comment: i think u are  using form somewhere that is why it is showing ? in the url Can u show your index.blade.php

Comment: Did you clear the route cache? The old route syntax does still work in Laravel 8 by the way

Comment: @GertB. I didnt, aaand, it helped. kinda, i had to add to my route / after object. Finnaly it looks like this: Route::get('/object/'.'{id}','FrontendController@object')->name('object');

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to clear routes cache using php artisan route:cache and to add missing / in route

```
Route::get('/object/'.'{id}','FrontendController@object')->name('object');
```

Comment: `'/object/'.'{id}'` is the same as `'/object/{id}'` so thats not needed...

Comment: @GertB. I know that, its a bit clearer to read for me tho. Thank you